# Does the magnetic flux spin in the same direction when the electric field is growing and collapsing?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

I have three concentric iron pipes, stacked inside each other.  It looks like a bulls-eye when viewed from above.

To the innermost and outermost pipes I have connected a battery through a switch.  When I close the switch, a voltage is applied between the innermost and outermost cylinders.  So there is an E field between them.

The middle pipe is not attached to anything.

I flick the switch on and off.

Every time the E field builds up, or collapses, a B field is induced.

curl B = dE/dt

Does the B field spin the same direction when I close the switch, and the E field builds up, as when I open the switch, and the E field collapses?

It looks like, from the above Maxwell's equation, that the B field will spin in different directions in these two circumstances.  Is that correct?

So, will the iron pipe in the middle ever get magnetized?  Or will it get magnetized first one way, then the opposite way, with a net effect of zero?

Answer (score 0):

The two B-fields do not have the same direction. If you consider for switching the switch off the same area that you considered to find the B-field when you turned the switch on, then you have a changing E-field that pierces that area in the same way with the only exception that the E-field is now decreasing in magnitude rather than increasing. So, by the Ampere-Maxwell equation in its integral form, you get a B-field in the opposite direction from the other case. You can see this just by watching the Ampere-Maxwell equation. You have the exact same terms but now the d/dt will give you a minus sign.
You can also see it through the differential equation curlB=dE/dt(all vectors). The dE/dt just gives negative rather than positive sign when you consider the case of switching it off. So, you get the opposite curl.

As for the middle pipe, yes, it will get magnetized. The B-field is produced by the dE/dt. So, it exists when the E-field changes. Your comment about the zero net effect is invalid, because you are implying that we have the two opposing B-fields at the same time, which means that the E-field changes in two ways at the same time! You only have one E-field, so one dE/dt, so one B-field at a time. (I am not taking into consideration the secondary E-field that the B-field will induce, it will be much weaker than the original E-field)